# Executing last launched debug/run from plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for our eclipse-based IDE at work. I currently have the plugin display a button in the toolbar. Now, when the user presses this button, i want the plugin to execute the "Run last launced" or "Debug last launched" command (in addition to some other things). I can't find any tutorial or documentation on this anywhere. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Or is there perhaps a way to launch any debug/run?